My list view is not displaying when I launch the app on a phone
I am doing an android bluetooth app to connect to my hc-05 bluetooth module and eventually to control the rc boat i made. I've encountered a problem when I launched the app on my phone and the list view did not display.(i am doing this project on android studio)
this is my code in the activity_main.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select A Pairing Device"
            android:textColor="#0033FF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pair" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

and this is the code in MainActivity(there is more to it of course but this is my code specifically for the listview
private void pairedDevicesList() {
        // Check if the app has the necessary permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission not granted, request it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH},
                    REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
            return; // Exit the method early, permission request is pending
        }

        // Permission is granted, proceed with listing paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
                list.add(bt.getName());
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
        devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener);
    }

    private final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = (parent, view, position, id) -> {
        String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length()-17);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BoatControl.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
        startActivity(i);
    };

and i call the method in onCreate()
btnPaired.setOnClickListener(v -> pairedDevicesList());

Please leave your code complete.
Add your code complete to check it.
try this:
package com.example.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION = 2;
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";
    private Button btnPaired;
    private ListView devicelist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPaired = findViewById(R.id.button);
        devicelist = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            init();
        }else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            }, MY_PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    init();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if ( myBluetooth==null ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth device not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else if ( !myBluetooth.isEnabled() ) {
            Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnBTon, 1);
        }

        // Check Bluetooth permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission not granted, request it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH);
        } else {
            // Permission already granted
            // You can perform Bluetooth operations here
        }

        btnPaired.setOnClickListener(v -> pairedDevicesList());
    }


    private void pairedDevicesList() {
        // Check if the app has the necessary permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission not granted, request it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH},
                    REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
            return; // Exit the method early, permission request is pending
        }

        // Permission is granted, proceed with listing paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
                list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
        devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener);
    }

    private final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = (parent, view, position, id) -> {
        String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length()-17);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BoatControl.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
        startActivity(i);
    };
}


changing the layout did not work but i will leave my whole code here: https://github.com/zaruuunchi/BoatControl

I fiexed you problem, you had a problem in your permissions.

Thank you very much but it still does not display the listview. Could it be because of the phone I use, because when I open the app with the new code there is a message "Permission denied"?

okay i fixed the problem as I did not have everything needed in my AndroidManifest.xml file and my app is now working fine!Thank you so much for the help!!
